# AccessViolation when calling SymSetOptions after stack overflow

Tags: c++, winapi

I am currently hacking around a solution to make errors easier to debug.

so i have a allready defined `main` and the user needs to define `wrappermain` that will replace the use of `main`:

```
int main(int ac, char** av)
{
  __try {
    return wrappermain(ac, av);
  } __except(HandleException(GetExceptionCode(), GetExceptionInformation()) {
    return 1;
  }
}
```

now in the `HandleException` function i load the symbol information and set some options:

```
if (!SymInitialize(process, symSearchPath, false))
    return;

DWORD symOptions = SymGetOptions();
symOptions |= SYMOPT_LOAD_LINES | SYMOPT_UNDNAME;
SymSetOptions(symOptions);
```

this construct works like a charm but when i provoke a stack overflow with an endless recursion, i get a access violation on calling `SymSetOptions(symOptions)`

what could that be and how to get rid of that crash?

Comment: There is only about 7 kilobytes of stack space left at the HandleException() call, emergency space released by the SO handler.  With no backstop in place anymore to generate another SO when you call a function that needs a large amount of stack space..  Kaboom with AV is next.  Some exceptions are just too nasty to handle gracefully, they named a programmer's web site after this one :)

Comment: @HansPassant wow, this sounds nice, whats the name of that site? maybe there is a lot of helpfull information on it (starting recursion again) ;)

Comment: Wrong solution. You really should be using [MiniDumpWriteDump](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680360.aspx) instead. Bonus: You get as much or as little information in your minidump as you request. And you don't have to ship PDB's with your application.

Comment: @IInspectable good point. i will try to add that into my error handler. BUT could in the case of a `stack overflow` the call itself cause another error due missing page memory? (as RbMm stated)

Answer (score 1):

The core problem here is the stack, obviously. You have a stack overflow (corrupt/unusable), and you want to handle it with a stack-based exception handler. That's not going to work well. I've even surprised you get this far; your exception handler has to be found by walking the call stack back to find a handler. And walking tat stack is going to be a problem if there's been an overflow and part of that stack is missing in action.

Anyway, I suspect the direct cause is the lack of a guard page on the stack. The stack isn't fully allocated up front. Instead, there's a guard page at the end of the allocation. Pushing too much causes a page fault, which usually leads to a successful stack growth. But when there's no space left, the overflow is fatal and the guard page is gone.

The fix may very well be to have *another* thread. It would poll a global flag (`DWORD` so atomic) and sleep if nothing happens. Your exception handler would just need to set the flag, and that doesn't require a working stack. This unlocks the helper thread, who then (using its fresh stack) calls the relevant methods.

Vectored Exception Handling may look like a workaround, but it has severe restrictions on what you can do in a handler.

Comment: ok this explaination is awesome and awefull. so i could implement the error handling in a separated thread, no biggie but if i want to print a call stack of crashed thread i will run in the same problem. or did i miss something?

Comment: Have the crashed thread pass not a global `DWORD` but a `UINT_PTR` with the stack base address. But obviously the call stack is rather large for a stack overflow !

Comment: for this it would be enough to get the first stack frame to get the current function that is causing the issue

Comment: @Zaiborg: The first stack frame (bottom of stack) is `main`. And the last stack frame (top) is corrupted.

Comment: woops, i ment the top one ,)

Answer (score 1):

"what could that be" - this and must be. because not enough stack space. in  HandleException you run at same stack point where exception occur. you have only 1 page (4096 bytes) of stack space. so call of function which require big stack space again raise exception. and this new already will be fatal - because already no stack space at all, even 1 page not exist. so if you view STATUS_STACK_OVERFLOW - you must just return EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER and already in __except(){..} block (in this point stack pointer already will be revert) again check for if (GetExceptionCode()==STATUS_STACK_OVERFLOW) - de allocate some stack space and set PAGE_GUARD again in bottom allocated page. if not do this - next stack overflow for your app already will be fatal(you not have 1 page in stack)

Comment: is it possible to access the exception information while inside the `__except(){}` block?

Comment: direct - no(* - but), because this already will be 'under' stack pointer, but you can copy this and than access in __except(){} block, but because we speak about user mode stack in widows, we really can safe access data and under stack pointer in some case,like this. so you can simply save pointer to GetExceptionInformation() in local varitable and tan use it. and create separate thread for handle this exception absolute not need, we can do this and from current thread

Answer (score 0):

```
            EXCEPTION_POINTERS ep;
            __try {
                return wrappermain(ac, av);
            }
            __except(memcpy(&ep,GetExceptionInformation(), sizeof(EXCEPTION_POINTERS)), HandleException(GetExceptionCode(),GetExceptionInformation())){
                if (GetExceptionCode() == STATUS_STACK_OVERFLOW)
                {

    #ifdef _WIN64
    #define GUARD_PAGE_COUNT 3
    #define COMMIT_PAGE_COUNT 6
    #else
    #define GUARD_PAGE_COUNT 1
    #define COMMIT_PAGE_COUNT 2
    #endif
//in ntdll exist special api for this - RtlResetStackOverflow, but it not exported
                    BOOL fOk = FALSE;

                    ::MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION mbi;
                    if (VirtualQuery(&mbi, &mbi, sizeof(mbi)))
                    {
                        if ((GUARD_PAGE_COUNT + COMMIT_PAGE_COUNT) << PAGE_SHIFT < RtlPointerToOffset(mbi.AllocationBase, mbi.BaseAddress))
                        {

                            mbi.BaseAddress = (PBYTE)mbi.BaseAddress - ((GUARD_PAGE_COUNT + COMMIT_PAGE_COUNT) << PAGE_SHIFT);
                            if (mbi.AllocationBase < mbi.BaseAddress)
                            {
                                ULONG OldProtect;
                                fOk = VirtualFree(mbi.AllocationBase, RtlPointerToOffset(mbi.AllocationBase, mbi.BaseAddress), MEM_DECOMMIT)
                                    &&
                                    VirtualProtect(mbi.BaseAddress, GUARD_PAGE_COUNT << PAGE_SHIFT, PAGE_READWRITE|PAGE_GUARD, &OldProtect);
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```